# Swiper slider error startAutoplay is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I got a problem with swiper slider. I would like my swiper stop on mouse enter and continue on mouseleave. But my console shows me an error --> swiper.stopAutoplay is not a function, but the console log is displayed. And the same with startAutoplay. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      loop: true,
      speed:2000,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 3500,
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
    });

(function($) {
$('.swiper-container').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    console.log('stop autoplay');
    swiper.stopAutoplay();
  })

  $('.swiper-container').on('mouseleave', function(e){
    console.log('start autoplay');
    swiper.startAutoplay();
  })
})(jQuery);


  </script>
```

Comment: Ok. I figured it out :) It should be swiper.stop.autoplay & swiper.start.autoplay

Comment: It's actually: `swiper.autoplay.stop()` and `swiper.autoplay.start()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version `4.3.5` you must use `autoplay.stop` and `autoplay.start`. For example:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.my-swiper');
$('.my-swiper').hover(function() {
    mySwiper.autoplay.stop();
}, function() {
    mySwiper.autoplay.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running 5.1.0.
After console.logging swiper reference i saw that for each tab was specific one created.
So in the loop when i was hiding the tabs just needed to:

```
swiper[i].autoplay.stop();
```

And on tab click showing the tab:

```
swiper[i].autoplay.start();
```

So thanks to answer above by @nick i was able to get this running.